# XML can't be opened in a browser

Tags: xml

I've an XML file like this:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<News size="48011">
<Link>http://www.nuoto.it/leggi.php?leggiID=27592</Link>
<Title>Harlem Shake all'italiana</Title>
<Subtitle>by Atlantide Elmas Swimming Team</Subtitle>
<Body><img src="http://www.nuoto.it/foto_news/ridim-elams2013.jpg" style="float:left;margin-left:0px;margin-right:5px;" />&nbsp;Era nell'aria che prima o poi &nbsp;arrivasse l'Harlem Shake mania versione Italia, ecco di seguito la prima proposta nostrana realizzata dagli amici dell' ASD ATLANTIDE ELMAS SWIMMING TEAM, disponibile on line sul canale Facebook di Swimming Channel.  Attenzione al contagio!  &nbsp;        &nbsp;</Body>
</News>
```

When I open it with a browser I get the following error:

```
error on line 1 at column 3: xmlParsePI : no target name
```

The XML file like this work fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<News size="123">
<Link>aaa</Link>
<Title>bbbb</Title>
<Subtitle>ccc</Subtitle>
<Body>ddd</Body>
</News>
```

I have to preserve the HTML code inside the tags
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<? xml
  ^
```

You aren't allowed a space at the start of a processing instruction.

That should be `<?xml`

Comment: You're right...I was looking for something particular and I didn't see the obvious error.
Thank you so much!