# Get value of XML element from a HTTP Socket response

Tags: xml, sockets, cakephp, httprequest

I have a controller that sends requests using an HTTP Socket, and gives responses in `xml` format. I am using cakephp 2.6.
Here is my code to get response body:

```
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();            
    $response = $HttpSocket->request($request);
    $resulthit = $response->body;
```

When I try to print the response body, it returns this in my browser:

```
-2201502101153512eFXcByWLUHvQmYC0EHMn2JVxcpyzozBcek uid dan pwd
```

But when I look at the source of page, this is what I see:

```
<? xml version="1.0" ?>
  <PUSH>
   <STATUS>-2</STATUS>
   <SMSCMESSAGEID>20150210133953</SMSCMESSAGEID>
   <GUID>knDlIBuUZf6zixlhbbxxLoxhEUGZTWPD</GUID>
   <MSG>cek uid dan pwd</MSG>
  </PUSH>
```

How I can get value of XML element above?
I want the STATUS and GUID.

I've already tried:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resulthit);
```

But I only get an error in return that says

```
 "String could not be parsed as XML"
```

Comment: You should get a lot of warnings explaining what's wrong, not just that exception message. [**Spaces before processing instruction targets**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955789/solved-xml-cant-be-opened-in-a-browser) are not allowed.

Comment: yeah you right but unfortunately the host that I'am used for Http Socket only give me that response and I am not authorized to edit the file that give that response

Comment: Well, if that is really what they return, then you should tell them that their API is buggy and needs to get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CakePHP Xml class:[CakePHP XML class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html)

The reason the code cannot be parsed as XML is because you have < pre > tags surrounding it, Im guessing because you are trying to do debug($something).

At the top of the controller include the XML class:

```
//First Load the Utility Class
App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
```

in the controller action do the following:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
pr(Xml::toArray(Xml::build($thexmlvariable)));
```

That way you can test it then you should use the ajax layout (A blank layout).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I already try that but error message in return: "XML cannot be read "

Comment: have you tried simply using file_get_contents on the URL? As long as the server is returning valid XML then XML class should be able to build it and output it as an array

Answer (score 1):

well finally I jump to conclusion that xml I get from Http response not valid due to 'Spaces before processing instruction targets' 
I have try with another 'dummy file response' with valid xml and it give me what I want.